# How can I upload a lot of pictures from the gallery in phone to Firebase storage?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm building an application on Android and looking for a way to upload a lot of images at once.

I managed to upload each picture separately but not together

Would appreciate help :)

Comment: Can you show your code of what you have tried so far? What part isn't working? Please review [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript (since I have the example already):

```
// set it up
firebase.storage().ref().constructor.prototype.putFiles = function(files) { 
  var ref = this;
  return Promise.all(files.map(function(file) {
    return ref.child(file.name).put(file);
  }));
}

// use it!
firebase.storage().ref().putFiles(files).then(function(metadatas) {
  // Get an array of file metadata
}).catch(function(error) {
  // If any task fails, handle this
});
```

From: https://gist.github.com/mcdonamp/d4f1327b58ad69334ef06327184df790

Same thing can be done with Java using the `Task` API.